# How to replace text on a screen after delay?

Tags: python, windows, replace, delay

I am **very new** to Python and I would like to know how I would clear a text that has been printed and add another piece of text. For example, I would like to display "Hello" then program with a delay of 10 seconds to replace text with another text "Goodbye". I am using Python 3.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: maybe `os.system("cls")` ... more than that you get alot more complicated ... really on windows its easier to just write a gui program

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import os

print ('hello there')
time.sleep(10) # this will BLOCK your program for 10 seconds
os.system('cls') # clear the screen, since cls is the clear screen command for windows
print ('bye')
input() # this is to wait to user to enter something to exist
```

version 2, using some 'visual' effects :D

```
import time
import os

print ('hello there')
for i in range(1, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('.')
os.system('cls')
print ('bye')
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once text is sent to stdout, there really isn't a good way to change it. What you probably want to do would require a UI library such as tkinter (which comes with Python) or [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org). Then you can create a Window with a label widget that can change every few seconds. You might be able to use Python's [curses library](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) too, but I have yet to see a coherent tutorial on how you would use that for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Python's output is based on an abstraction of "output is just a file that you can write to", so there's no way to do this cross-platform.

However, if you want it to work in a Windows `cmd.exe` console (aka "DOS prompt"), and don't care about working inside IDLE, on Unix, over a network, etc., you can use the MSVCRT console I/O APIs.

Unfortunately, the limited set of [console I/O APIs built into the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) doesn't include the clear function. But you can look for third-party extended console I/O libraries on PyPI, or use PyWin32 to call the MSVCRT functions directly.

Or you can use a cheap hack:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['cls'])
```

This just calls the `cls` function, which does everything for you.